# Jpeg values in decimal are being saved but wont display image

Tags: image, jpeg

I currently took a photo with a camera which returned to me all its values in decimal and after extracting the values my jpeg file are(i converted them to hex here but they were still saved in decimal)

FF
  D8
  FF
  FE
  00
  24
  30
  00
  9D
  08
  00
  00
  00
  00
  00
  00
  00
  00
  00
  00
  00
  00
  00
  00
  00
  F0
  00
  40
  01
  0C
  00
  32
............
  00
  54
  65
  6B
  D9
  9F
  FF
  FF
  D9

i saved theses value into a file called image.jpg (they were saved in decimal)
however the image file was not able to read it and I can not use the linux command convert as it tells me "Bogus marker length". What would i be doing wrong that doesnt allow me to see the image?

Comment: This make no sense because a camera normally returns binary values. There are all kinds of things you could be screwing up, including the byte ordering of integers.

Comment: The camera is a linksprite jpeg color camera ttl which allows me to capture output. its suppose to return to me hex values.

Comment: Have you run a JPEG dumping program on it.  The image source code here has one: http://www.colosseumbuilders.com/sourcecode/index.html